# What is the most efficient way to use incense?

Tags: pokemon-go

My girlfriend is addicted to Pokemon Go, and since there isn't a S.E. forum for mobile game addiction, I figured I'd be supportive instead.

Her apartment isn't near a Pokestop, so when we're hanging there the only way (it seems) for her to make any progress is to use incense. But the only Pokemon that show up don't seem to be very effective. Is there a way to maximize the effectiveness of incense?

Comment: Pokemon can turn up anywhere - not just near Pokestops (but lures can only be used on pokestops, which might be what you're thinking of). You can't really maximise the effectiveness of incense though - she really just needs to get out and about to catch more Pokemon, that's how the game works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the incense walk around. When you walk around at a speed if greater than 200m/minute you will encounter a Pokemon every 60 seconds. If you stay in place, you will encounter a Pokemon every 5 mins. So walk around if you have data.